# Does Brink use GFWL or Steamworks?

Tags: pc, steam, games-for-windows-live, brink

I heard in some previews that Brink would have used Steamworks but today I went on an online store and the PC cover shows the logo Game For Windows Live.

Can you clarify which is the truth? I am asking this because I am not a big fan of GWFL (to say it softly) and I would buy probably only if it use Steam infrastructure for matchmaking, ladders, server browsing and so on.

Comment: Do you like Steam, or do you dislike GFWL? Because if the cover shows that logo, it will have GFWL. If it has Steam support, that will be additional to GFWL.

Comment: I think you'll find that the box art is Games for Windows and *not* Games for Windows Live.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See the [Brink FAQ](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1404164) being maintained on the Steam forums:

> ### Q. Is BRINK a GFWL title?
>
> Nope. BRINK is a Steamworks title. BRINK carries the 'Games for Windows' moniker, which is different to GFWL. For a game to be certified for GFW, it has to meet the following requirements:
>
> - An "Easy Install" option that installs the title on a PC in the fewest possible steps and mouse clicks
> - Compatibility with the Windows Vista/ 7 Games Explorer
> - Installs and runs properly on x64 versions of Windows Vista/ 7 and is compatible with 64-bit processors (though the game itself can be 32-bit)
> - Supports normal and widescreen resolutions, such as 4:3 aspect ratio (800 x 600, 1024 x 768), 16:9 aspect ratio (1280 x 720, 1920 x 1080), and 16:10 aspect ratio (1280 x 800, 1440 x 900, 1680 x 1050, 1920 x 1200)
> - Supports parental controls and family settings features in Windows Vista/ 7
> - Supports launching from Windows Media Center
>
> ### Q. Can I activate a retail copy through Steam?
>
> BRINK uses Steamworks so retail copies can be activated through Steam.

Answer (score 1):

http://store.steampowered.com/app/22350/

It uses SteamWorks in the Steam version, it has Steam achievements, Steam leaderboards, etc...

Answer (score 0):

According to [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/22350/), it uses Steam for all those.